# Inference on Unlabeled Data in Semi-Supervised Learning and Determining Dataset Size

Tags: methodology, semi-supervised-learning

In semi-supervised learning, when a portion of unlabelled data is combined with labelled data during the training process, I'm wondering how one can perform inference specifically on the unlabelled data used for training. What are the recommended strategies or techniques for conducting inference on this subset of unlabelled data?

Additionally, considering a scenario where there is a substantial amount of unlabelled data available, how do you determine the appropriate dataset size to utilize in a semi-supervised training procedure? Are there any established methodologies or best practices for defining the size of the dataset used in such scenarios?